# php code with random function not working

Tags: php, file

In this program i want that name of the image gets changed after it has been displayed on the page

But it gets changed before it could be displayed ...

the text file is used to get the name of image and also to store the new name of image file

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("givename.txt", "r"); 

$d= fread($myfile,filesize("givename.txt"));  

fclose($myfile);

img src="?php echo "80/$d.jpg";?>">

$rand=(mt_rand(10,100));

$mfile = fopen("givename.txt", "w") ;

fwrite($mfile, $rand);

fclose($mfile);


rename("80"."/"."$d".".jpg","80"."/"."$rand".".jpg");
?>
```

Comment: Check your code could be run and without syntax error.

Comment: What is `img src` in your code?

Comment: image is kept in a directory named as 80, the name of image is same as string in the text file (givename.txt) , after random function is called the name of image gets changed and the new name is saved in the text file....... but what i want  is to display the image on page before random function gets implemented.....as soon image is shown the name gets change ... so if the user opens image in new tab it says error 404

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("givename.txt", "r"); 
$d= fread($myfile,filesize("givename.txt"));  
fclose($myfile);
 "<img src='80/$d.jpg'>";
$rand=(mt_rand(10,100));
$mfile = fopen("givename.txt", "w") ;
fwrite($mfile, $rand);
fclose($mfile);

rename("80"."/"."$d".".jpg","80"."/"."$rand".".jpg");
?>
```